# Как правильно использовать <!DOCTYPE html> в Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, blade

Проблема в том, что когда я подключаю просто `<!DOCTYPE html>` вверху *layout.blade.php* то в браузере оно отображается так:

```
<!--?php<!DOCTYPE html-->
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно, чтобы отображалось как в шаблоне:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из за этого, у меня пол шаблона летит. Если в коде через F12 исправить на второй вариант - все работает.

Код макета:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
...
</html>
```

Код файла, который его наследует

```
@extends('layouts.account.index')
```

---

Заметил еще одну странность: при выполнении все команды в консоли Artisan имеют приставку `<?php`. Например, `php artisan serve`:

```
<?phpLaravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

---

Как правильно?

Comment: Прикрепите код.

Comment: @РустамГимранов а как наследовать?

Comment: @Alpha <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Marketing Dashboard - Application Intel - SmartAdmin v4.0.1
    </title>

Comment: @РустамГимранов, так и сделал. Наследую свой лайоут в обычном блейде страницы... все равно не помогло

Comment: @РустамГимранов ну вот же, стандарт html при подключении чего либо.... Чем это поможет ?)

Comment: @РустамГимранов заметил еще одну странность... Все команды в php artisan... при исполнении имеют приставку <?php, например <?phpLaravel Framework 6.4.1...

Comment: @РустамГимранов да, тоже видел((

Comment: @РустамГимранов спасибо вам большое! Я не знаю как отблагодарить вас! Бегу домой чтобы исправить баг!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно во всех файлах в папке маршрутов `routes` после первого рядка с `<?php` добавить перенос строки:

```
<?php
// новая строка
```

Источник: [laravel is commenting out my view doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175156/4822490)